# Does realloc change pointer address?

Tags: c, function, malloc, realloc

Take this code for example:

```
Struct* allocSomething(void) {
    int n; 
    Struct *something = malloc(n*sizeof(Struct));
    return something;
}

Struct* reallocSomething(Struct **s) {
    int n;
    Struct *something = realloc(*s, (n*sizeof(int)) - 1 * sizeof(Struct));
    return something;
}

int main() {
    Struct *point = allocSomething();
    //code does something...
    point = reallocSomething();
    free(point);
}
```

My question is, after calling `reallocSomething`, `point` has still the same address returned by `allocSomething`? For example, if `point` have address `0x01`, when this pointer get reallocated by `reallocSomething`, is that address still `0x01`?

Comment: Compiler warnings are your friend. Enable and pay heed to them! And read the documentation.

Answer (score 9):

From the man page for [realloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc):

> ```
> void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
> ```
>
> ....
>
> realloc()  returns  a  pointer  to the newly allocated memory, which
>   is suitably aligned for any kind of variable **and  may  be  different 
>   from ptr**, or NULL if the request fails.  If size was equal to 0,
>   either NULL or a pointer suitable to be passed to free() is returned. 
>   If realloc() fails the original block is left untouched; it is not
>   freed or moved.

Since `realloc` may move the allocated memory to a new location, you need to account for this.

Answer (score 3):

Don't count on it staying at the same address. The system is allowed to move the whole affair to a different address for whatever reason. While the chunk of memory you're requesting is smaller, and it should logically fit in space vacated by the previous allocation, this is not an atomic operation and any interruption or timesharing can have something else grab that memory space.  There's probably other shenanigians with whatever system you're using, but standard-wise? Don't expect the address to remain the same. And don't expect it change either.

Comment: What does the (lack of ) atomicity have to do with anything?

Comment: It means the scheduler can interrupt the program and let something else run in the middle of the realloc call. You know, if his system has one of those.  If something else is running, it can malloc and take the address. I was trying to explain WHY the system would give him a new address instead of keeping the old one.

Comment: That still doesn't make any sense. Other programs cannot see the same memory (unless they use shared memory, which is not handled by `[m/c/re]alloc()` but by implementation-defined primitives (e.g. `mmap()`)). Other *threads* could potentially see non-atomicity of the `realloc()`call, but only if the allocation is handed to the other thread, then handed back before the `realloc()`-call finishes. Since this would require an unnecessary full copy *and* extra memory, this would only be a problem on an insane implementation. Face it, atomicity is a red herring for this.

Answer (score 0):

From the point of view of the Standard, unless realloc fails, the act of calling it will destroy not just the storage identified by the old pointer, but also the old pointer itself.  A compiler may behave in arbitrary and capricious fashion if code tries to access the old pointer other than by examining the bytes thereof, even if the bit pattern in that pointer happen to precisely match those of the new pointer.

Quality implementations may (and probably should) allow programs to use realloc in some ways beyond those required by the Standard (e.g. check whether an object has moved, and recompute pointers that identify portions thereof if it has, but don't bother which such computation if it hasn't moved) but the Standard defines no means via which indications can indicate whether or not they support such constructs.